# Show soft keyboard on search actionbar activation with SearchView

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089993/android-how-to-focus-actionbar-searchview) sets focus on the SearchView EditText when I activate a search from the ActionBar.  However the keyboard does not come up when it gains focus.  Shouldn't it, as it is just a normal EditText?  (Is it a normal EditText?)  This behaviour is seen on Android SDK level 11. (Samsung Galax Tab 7.7 with stock Android.)

I have a workaround at the moment that hooks in on the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method of my Activity, showing the keyboard.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        boolean menuSelectionHandeled = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        // menu_search is the id of the menu item in the ActionBar
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_search) {
               mInputManager.showSoftInput(null, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
        return menuSelectionHandeled;
    }
```

Where `mInputManager` is an instance of `InputMethodManager`.

The ActionBar is built with ActionBarSherlock, and since the target device is Android 3.x could this be the cause of the symptoms?  As per ActionBarSherlock's [FAQ](http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html) :

> The action bar on Android 3.x (also known as Honeycomb) does not
>   implement all of the features of the one in Android 4.x (Ice Cream
>   Sandwich). In order to provide a full action bar API on all platforms
>   as well as unify the styling across all versions of Android the custom
>   implementation is used.

Comment: Don't know if this really matters but i had a problem when my xml file contained a `EditText` as in the example files from ActionBarSherlock (ie: i couldn't get my callbacks for textchange etc to work) but when i changed that to a `SearchView` instead and added the proper callbacks it just started working as intended. Perhaps give that a try?

Comment: Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011091/how-can-i-focus-on-a-collapsible-action-view-edittext-item-in-the-action-bar-wh

Comment: Thanks @Anton that question makes me think there isn't a way to show the keyboard automatically.  He has the same workaround as me.  In my XML I definitely use a SearchView. Thanks

Comment: Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39635722/2535875

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getContext());
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```