# Unable to show keyboard automatically in the SearchView

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-softkeyboard, android-4.2-jelly-bean, searchview

The SearchView is focused by default, but when I try to show software keyboard - it doesn't happen:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

But when I click on the SearchView - it does. Why?

Comment: you are trying open the default keyboard

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Fixed!

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                            if (hasFocus) {
                                showInputMethod(view.findFocus());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

And

```
private void showInputMethod(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
          imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, do you think you could give me some advice/ideas over here http://goo.gl/E37NSu

Comment: It's been 11 years since this was solved and it still works!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

I encountered this problem with a SearchView that still would not open the keyboard, and was able to do so by adding a 200ms delay:

```
   mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(final View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(view.findFocus(), 0);
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Works and upvote! But in my case the problem was the 'SearchView' location in the actionbar, so if it helps someone...locate your searchView always visible, using  'showAsAction= "always"' in your xml, the keyboard appears immediately.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using **SearchView**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
      android:id="@+id/searchView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
      app:showAsAction="always"
      app:iconifiedByDefault="true"/>
```

Then just add it to your **onCreate** method :

```
final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 7):

What about using `setOnFocusChangeListener`?

```
searchview.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus){
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... what about this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089993/android-how-to-focus-actionbar-searchview

Answer (score 6):

**Best and simplest way to do it :**

```
        android:focusable="true"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Add above three lines into your xml under SearchView and see the magic....!!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
void focusSearchViewAndOpenOrCloseKeyboard(boolean focus) {
    searchView.setIconified(focus);
}
```

The [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#709) shows us that `SearchView` handles its own [closing and opening of the soft keyboard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#1010).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hint="@string/SERACH"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
```

Answer (score 0):

add `<requestFocus />` in your search view like this

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#e6e6e6">

            <requestFocus />

        </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions, but finally the only one that worked for me is the following:

kotlin version:

```kotlin
mSearchView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object: OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        mSearchView.requestFocus()
        val imm = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(mSearchView, 0)
        mSearchView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
    }
})
```

java version:

```java
mSearchView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mSearchView.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
        getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(mSearchView, 0);
        mSearchView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed the keyboard to automatically appear and have the searchView ready for typing with the cursor blinking.

This is [what worked](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.widget.SearchView/clearFocus) for me. In `onViewCreated`, I added these 2 specific lines:

```
binding.searchView.isIconified = false
binding.searchView.requestFocus()
```

Code:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.searchView.isIconified = false
    binding.searchView.requestFocus()
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue in next simple way.

SearchView menu item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@android:string/search_go"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

To expand SearchView and show keyboard programmatically call:

```
mMenuItemSearch.expandActionView();
mSearchView.setQuery("your default query test or null", true);
```

Tested with different showAsAction flags. As result keyboard does not shown when flag: "**always**". However everything works with flag: "**always|collapseActionView**"

*expandActionView() + setQuery("null or restored text", true);* can be called when view created (or restored) to show keyboard and focus on search. P.S: call *mSearchView.clearFocus();* after this two method to clear the focus.