# Showing the soft keyboard for SearchView on ActionBar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

We've got a SearchView on the ActionBar which is set to be non-iconified. As we don't have any content in the view until the user's entered something to search for, it would make sense to give the SearchView initial focus, and make sure the soft keyboard is showing ready for the user to enter text — otherwise they'll always have to first tap in the SearchView.

I can give the SearchView focus by just calling

```
searchView.requestFocus();
```

but I can't get the soft keyboard to appear. In another one of our Fragments I have an EditText which we want to be focused I *can* get the soft keyboard to appear there by calling

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

but this just doesn't work on the SearchView. It must surely be possible to get this to work.

Comment: Try it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39635722/2535875

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Further rummaging around StackOverflow and I found this question:

[Forcing the Soft Keyboard open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479504/forcing-the-soft-keyboard-open)

which contains a solution that worked for me:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).
    toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: This gets the keyboard up for me, but if doing that inside onCreateOptionsMenu(), I had to keep a flag to make sure I only ran this code once. Otherwise the keyboard will keep popping up again after you submit a search.

Comment: I had the same problem and found the SearchView solution here helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022715/unable-to-show-keyboard-automatically-in-the-searchview

Comment: This is useless, what happens if you have 2 views that can allow keyboard input?  You need more to get the keyboard to send the text to the correct view.

Answer (score 10):

I have a similar problem where none of the proposed solutions here worked. Some just didn't make the keyboard appear at all and some show a keyboard but the key presses there just do not work.

The only thing that worked was:

```
                    // hack for making the keyboard appear
                    searchView.setIconified(true);
                    searchView.setIconified(false);
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using a SearchView with setIconifiedByDefault(false). Testing with Android 4.4.2, the only way I could get the keyboard to actually show was to look at the source code for SearchView and mimic how it requested the keyboard to be shown. I've tried literally every other method I could find/think of and this is the only way I could get the keyboard to show reliably. Unfortunately, my method requires some reflection.

In onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu):

```java
searchView.requestFocus();
searchView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showSoftInputUnchecked();
    }
});
```

And then create a method to call the hidden method "showSoftInputUnchecked" in InputMethodManager:

```java
private void showSoftInputUnchecked() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if (imm != null) {
        Method showSoftInputUnchecked = null;
        try {
            showSoftInputUnchecked = imm.getClass()
                    .getMethod("showSoftInputUnchecked", int.class, ResultReceiver.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // Log something
        }

        if (showSoftInputUnchecked != null) {
            try {
                showSoftInputUnchecked.invoke(imm, 0, null);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // Log something
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // Log something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As with all solutions that access methods not in the public API, I can't promise that this won't break with new versions of Android.

Comment: The only answer that works. How sad is the soft keyboard situation on Android? Its pathetic.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
private SearchView mSearchView;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView =
            (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        mSearchView.setFocusable(true);
        mSearchView.setIconified(false);
        mSearchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna show the soft keyboard and focus on the input box, you can try

```
final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
menuItem.expandActionView();//expand show soft keyboard

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_actionbar_search"
    liven:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always" //always
    liven:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not show keyboard every time you come on activity

searchview.clearFocus();

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```kotlin
 fun View.showKeyboard() {
    val viewWithFocus = findFocus()
    val windowToken = viewWithFocus?.windowToken
    if (viewWithFocus != null && windowToken != null) {
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(viewWithFocus, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use expandView method :
Your onCreateOptionsMenu could be something like this:

```
         @Override                                                                                                     
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {                                                          
 //Used to put dark icons on light action bar                                                              

     final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());                   


       MenuItem mitem = menu.add("Search");                                                                  

       mitem.setIcon(ic_search_inverse)                                                                      
            .setActionView(searchView)                                                                       
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

        mitem.expandActionView();                                                      

        listsearch.setOnItemClickListener(this);                                                             

 return     true;                                                                                              
      }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try what I did. This worked well for me.

```
    //set query change listener
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            /**
             * hides and then unhides search tab to make sure keyboard disappears when query is submitted
             * 4 = INVISIBLE
             * 0 = VISIBLE
             */
                  searchView.setVisibility(4);
                  searchView.setVisibility(0);
            return false;
        }

     });
```