# How do I show the soft keyboard after requesting focus on a SearchView in a Button's onClick listener?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a SearchView and a button.

The button has an onClick listener that successfully focuses the SearchView, but the keyboard only shows when I actually tap on the SearchView.

I want the keyboard to show in addition to focusing the SearchView when I click the button.

Here's the button listener code inside `onCreate`:

```kotlin
binding.emptyStateSearch.setOnClickListener {
  searchView.requestFocus() // this works and makes the cursor active in the searchView
  val imm: InputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
  imm.showSoftInput(searchView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT) // but this does not show the keyboard
}
```

I also tried `imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0)` *which works but it is deprecated*, so I don't want to rely on it.

I tried it without `SHOW_IMPLICIT`: `showSoftInput(searchView, 0)`. Doesn't work.

I tried putting a timer before calling `showSoftInput` but that doesn't work either.

The strange thing is that the `SearchView.isFocusable` returns `true` but upon calling `requestFocus` on it, `isFocused` returns `false` even though I can clearly see the cursor inside it.

Comment: Have you tried any answers from this post? (linked the one I use quite often): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52588685/15749574

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it with a simple workaround from this thread: [Showing the soft keyboard for SearchView on ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223623/showing-the-soft-keyboard-for-searchview-on-actionbar?rq=2)

```
searchView.setIconified(true);
searchView.setIconified(false);
```