# SearchView gains focus and opens keyboard when returning from another activity

Tags: android, keyboard, searchview

When I return from another activity to the main activity, the searchView gains focus and the keyboard opens, I managed to stop the keyboard from opening by using:

```
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

but this is not sufficient, if the actionbar drop down menu is opened and closed the keyboard reappears, because the searchView still has focus (remember I only closed the keyboard). I have tried to get a reference to the searchView and make it lose focus, but this has not worked.

So basically, I just want the searchView to never have focus or prompt the keyboard to open, unless the searchView text area is actually touched.

Comment: See this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39635722/2535875

Answer (score 22):

This is due to the `SearchView` being the first focusable view when the activity is brought back into view - the same issue [can be seen for `EditText`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1555109/1217087).

The solution is the same - set an earlier view in the hierarchy to focusable. In my case, this was the `Toolbar` my `SearchView` was on top of:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/search_activity_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    ... />
```

Now I can gain focus on my `SearchView` when entering the activity (`clearFocus(); requestFocus(...);`), then when you exit the activity via a search result, then return by pressing Back, the keyboard is in the same state as when you left.

Note that some of the other solutions on the linked question, namely [setting `windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"` on the Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611031/1217087) did *not* work for me.

Comment: I'm really sad that "focusableInTouchMode" is the _only_ way to make this work :( But it works.

Answer (score 7):

Leveraging on [Adam S' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256263/1467923), if you don't have any earlier `View` in the hierarchy before the `SearchView`, you could always include a dummy `View` like so:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    ... />
```

This also worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

while initializing

```
mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

And when came back, put this in `onResume()` or `onCreateOptionsMenu`(if search is in menu)

```
mSearchView.setIconified(false);
```

Then keyboard won't open when you come back until you click on edit text of `searchview`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me in onResume();

```
searchview.clearFocus();
```