# Keyboard pop up when back from another intent if setIconifiedByDefault is false

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-actionbar, searchview

[image]

Hi guys. When I open Activity 2 from Fragment 1 with intent and press back on Activity 2, my keyboard would pop up automatically if setIconifiedByDefault is false when I create the searchView in actionBar in Fragment 1. I tried to remove `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);`. Everything works perfect (nothing pop up when I press back in Activity 2) but I cannot get the exact layout I want. Any suggestions to avoid the keyboard pop up?

In Fragment 1, I have below code to create searchView in actionBar

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.homesearchbar, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { return false; }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { return false; }
    });
}
```

Edit - homesearchbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title=""
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: maybe try to hide the soft keyboard in onResume method in activity 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your keyboard state hidden then you should enter this in your `onResume()` method: And this is happening because your textfield always takes the focus whenever you start or resume your activity/fragment. To stop that one way is the following:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourTextField.getWindowToken(), 0);

}
```

Or if you can't get your searchfield in onResume then use this instead:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

And another way is to declare `"stateHidden"` attribute in activity tag
in your manifest.

You can also set `setFocusable(false)` for `searchView` and `setFocusable(true)` in your fragment 1. So that it won't take the focus. and all credits to you for this.

Comment: ```yourTextField``` textField is the searchView in actionBar. How can I get the variable from onResume function?

Comment: @PakHoCheung you need to declare your searchView globally.. :)

Comment: @PakHoCheung if you still can't do it please see my updated answer.

Comment: Tried to declare searchView globally and hide the keyboard in onResume, keyboard also pop up. I also tried to put ```getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);``` on Fragment 1's onResume method or on Activity 1's onResume method. Keyboard still pop up. I can see searchView is editing.

Comment: then add clear focus () to your searchview explicitly.like

searchView.clearfocus();

Comment: also tried  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Comment: then please take a look at this answer it may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624282/searchview-gains-focus-and-opens-keyboard-when-returning-from-another-activity

Comment: also there is a work around too. take a edittext and set it's visibility to gone and give it the focus. then enter the above code. it will work i believe.

Comment: Ok let me try. Will get back to you.

Comment: sure do let me know. :)

Comment: I am creating a menu. Am I doing on a wrong way? See my edit. Thanks for the help.

Comment: God damn. Finally fix it by setFocusable(false) for searchView and setFocusable(true) for one of layout in Fragment 1. You can change your answer, so that I can vote. Thanks a lot

Comment: @PakHoCheung it is wired though but happy that it solved your problem and I have edited the answer all credits to you :)